# Where to cognito secret hash key

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm attempting to create a simple android/aws project and I'm receiving an error and I don't know where to look. Note sure if it matters but i'm attempting to connect my app to an identity pool to have users log in with an email address.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //AWS Housekeeping
    public static PinpointManager pinpointManager;
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    private final String POOL_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
    private final String USER_POOL = "xxxxxxxxx";

    private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;
    private AWSConfiguration awsConfiguration;

    private Button loginBtm;
    private Button createUserBtm;
    private EditText emailField;
    private EditText passwordField;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createUserBtm = findViewById(R.id.createButton);
        loginBtm = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        emailField = findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        passwordField = findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        final Intent newUserIntent = new Intent(this, NewUserActivity.class);
        final Intent signInIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);


        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {

                // Obtain the reference to the AWSCredentialsProvider and AWSConfiguration objects
                awsCredentialsProvider = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider();
                awsConfiguration = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration();


                // Use IdentityManager #getUserID to fetch the identity id.
                IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getUserID(new IdentityHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onIdentityId(String identityId) {
                        Log.d("YourMainActivity", "Identity ID = " + identityId);

                        // Use IdentityManager#getCachedUserID to
                        //  fetch the locally cached identity id.
                        final String cachedIdentityId =
                                IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getCachedUserID();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleError(Exception exception) {
                        Log.d("YourMainActivity", "Error in retrieving the identity: " + exception);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).execute();





        createUserBtm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(newUserIntent);
            }
        });

        loginBtm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(emailField.getText().toString() != null && passwordField.getText().toString() != null){
                    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(getApplicationContext(), POOL_ID, USER_POOL, null, Regions.US_EAST_1);
                    CognitoUser cognitoUser = userPool.getUser();
                    cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
                    startActivity(signInIntent);
                }
            }
        });



    }

    class loginUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
        String username;
        String password;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

            username = emailField.getText().toString();
            password = passwordField.getText().toString();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //Instantiate an AmazonBynamoDBMapperClient
            AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
            this.dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
                    .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
                    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                    .build();

            return null;
        }
    }


    final AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) {
            Log.i("Success: ", userSession.getAccessToken().getJWTToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(emailField.toString(), passwordField.toString(), null);

            // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);

            // Allow the sign-in to continue
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();

        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            Log.i("ERROR:", exception.getMessage().toString());

        }
    };
}
```

```
04-15 18:32:09.618 5880-5880/com.ronone.securesender I/ERROR:: Unable to verify secret hash for client xxxxxxxxxxx (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 4eca8202-40db-11e8-a05e-217eccab3af8)
```

Where can I locate this secret hash key? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link. Secret hash needs to be calculated using username, clientId and clientSecretId. The python implementation is provided in the link. Translate it your preferred language.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-unable-to-verify-secret-hash/